# WordPress rename "home" page link to "blog" in nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

In the default word press install this code:
`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>` which displays the main pages menu.

How do I rename the home link?

When I log into the admin area this page the homepage is not displayed in the pages only "Sample Page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using URL '`wp-admin/nav-menus.php`' or moving to Admin -> Appearance -> Menu

Comment: This appears to create a new menu, is there no way to edit the default menu. I have got to the point now I am not fussed if I need to edit the the core wp files.